# String litteral not properly closed by double quote

Tags: java

on line 22 i get the message "String litteral not properly closed by double quote".
What is wrong with the System.out.printf?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Tenta131219main {
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum, ant10, ant5, ant1;
    String indata1;
    System.out.print( "\nAnge din summa: " );
    sum = sc.nextInt();
    if (sum <= 10)
        System.out.println("For lagt belopp!!");
else {
System.out.print( "\nAnge sort: " );
indata1 = sc.next();
indata1 = indata1.substring(0,2);
ant10 = 0;
while (sum >= 10) {
    sum = sum - 10;
    ant10 = ant10 +1;
}
ant5 = sum / 5;
ant1 = sum % 5;
System.out.printf("\n%s blir\n%d tior %d femmor %d enkronor
\n", indata1, ant10, ant5, ant1);
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`String` literals cannot span multiple lines like you have here

```
System.out.printf("\n%s blir\n%d tior %d femmor %d enkronor
\n", indata1, ant10, ant5, ant1);
```

This is described in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

> It is a compile-time error for a line terminator to appear after the
>   opening `"` and before the closing matching `"`.

Change it to

```
System.out.printf("\n%s blir\n%d tior %d femmor %d enkronor\n", indata1, ant10, ant5, ant1);
```

Or close the literal with a `"` and add a `+` for concatenation.

```
System.out.printf("\n%s blir\n%d tior %d femmor %d enkronor" +
"\n", indata1, ant10, ant5, ant1);
```